# Getting the value of the clicked li element

Tags: javascript, event-listener

First of all I'm adding an EventListener to the ul, as follows:

```
action_list_ul.addEventListener("click", set_ua_value, false);
```

The set_ua_value job is to:

• Listen to every click made on the ul childs (li elements)
• get the value (innerHTML?) of the a tag inside the clicked li

```
<ul id="action-list">
<li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
<li><a href="#">bar</a></li>
</ul>
```

In case foo was clicked on, I need to retrieve the "foo" string.

Since I'm fairly new to javascript, I'm not sure how to get the actual "this"
of the clicked li.

I do not want to use jQuery. Thanks :)

Comment: Even when I think about it, I'm still not sure how the actual instance will be passed into the function..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick and dirty way is to bind the event to the list, and filter by anchor tags:

**JS**

```
var action_list_ul = document.getElementById('action-list');
action_list_ul.addEventListener("click", set_ua_value, false);

function set_ua_value (e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName == "A") {
       console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
    }

}
```

**[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/alowaf/2/edit)**

Alternately, you can filter by `LI`, and access the anchor through `firstChild` or `childNodes[0]`.

Comment: Can you explain why this is "dirty" ?

Comment: It's not as elegant as the delegation methods provided by a javascript library, which can mitigate the messiness of vanilla js solutions like this : )

Comment: Although there's no whitespace between the `<li>` and `<a href=...`, `childNodes[0]` would return a text node if there's actually any whitespace in between, while `.children[0]` won't

Comment: You don't need the `e.target &&` part. And one doesn't need a library to do selector-based event delegation, though it would be overkill for simple situations like this.

Comment: function set_ua_value(e) {document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;} works well. any reason not to use it?

Comment: @CrazyTrain thanks for the edits. I'm not saying you *have* to use a library for tasks like this, but when the little tasks start adding up...

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```
var win = window, doc = document, bod = doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function actionListValue(element, func){
  var cn = element.childNodes;
  for(var i=0,l=cn.length; i<l; i++){
    if(cn[i].nodeType === 1){
      var nc = cn[i].childNodes;
      for(var n=0,c=nc.length; n<c; n++){
        if(nc[n].nodeType === 1){
          nc[n].onclick = function(){
            func(this.innerHTML);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
actionListValue(E('action-list'), set_ua_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo"); 
foo.addEventListener("click", modifyText);

function modifyText(e) {
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML); 
}
```

In this case the binding would have to be with the `a` elements.

```
<ul id="action-list">
    <li><a href="#" id="foo">foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="bar">bar</a></li>
</ul>
```

**[JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/ayajoh/1/edit)**